# Make phone settings as vibrate never

Tags: android, vibration

I wrote this code to disable the vibrate off in sound setting. But it is not working on Samsung galaxy s (GT-I9003).

Code snippet:

```
public class A_TestActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);                          
    am.setVibrateSetting
    (AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER,AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
  }
}
```

Also put the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Please advice if there is any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You need to catch Some kind of Receive SMS or somthing else.
Use the BroadcastReceiver and While Activity is onCreate.
if your device receive the SMS. that code will function. sorry i didn't test yet.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But my requirement is to set the vibrate mode as "never" in settings screen and device should worked like that.It should effect in settings screen also.

Comment: That code snippet works on Your Activity is Alive. That is Problem.

Comment: The code is working fine but it is not updating the profile screen data. It set all the things perfect except the settings screen.